# How could i create helm-find-file function that copies selected file path

Tags: helm

Is there a way to create helm-find-files function that would copy file path upon completion instead of opening it? It's important that original helm-find-files function would still open files.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use <kbd>C-c C-i</kbd> or <kbd>C-c TAB</kbd> (`helm-copy-to-buffer`), it copies current candidate or selected candidate(s) into the current buffer, it works for all helm commands. For `helm-find-file`, it inserts the absolute (full) path, not just the basename.